# Make empty file for each subfolder using subfolders' name in Python

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system, os.walk

If I have a folder structure as follows:

```
folder
        \ sub1\sub1_1
        \ sub1\sub1_2
        \ sub1\sub1_3
        .
        .
        .
        \ sub2\sub2_1
        \ sub2\sub2_2
        \ sub2\sub2_3
        .
        .
        .
```

I want make files for each subfolder use subfolders' name. How can I do it in Python? Thanks.
Expected result:

```
folder
        \ sub1\sub1_1\sub1_1.xlsx
        \ sub1\sub1_2\sub2_2.xlsx
        \ sub1\sub1_3\sub3_3.xlsx
        .
        .
        .
        \ sub2\sub2_1\sub2_1.xlsx
        \ sub2\sub2_2\sub2_2.xlsx
        \ sub2\sub2_3\sub2_3.xlsx
        .
        .
        .
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
import os
dir_name = "D:/folder"     
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name, topdown=False):
    for subfolder in dirs:
        print(subfolder)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that recursively:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = "add/your/path"

def write_files(path):
    folders = [f for f in listdir(path) if not isfile(join(path, f))]
    if len(folders) == 0:
        #Writing the actual File
        open(path+"/"+path.split("/")[-1]+".xlsx", "w+")
    else:
        for folder in folders:
            write_files(path+"/"+folder)

write_files(mypath)
```

Note that this will only create textfiles with an xlsx ending and not actual excel files.
Therefore you can install some library that is capable of creating excel files

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I think this may be helpful to solve this problem. What do you think? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252754/iterate-all-subfolders-and-ocr-images-in-python